# Notation for product of arbitrary list

Tags: notation, products

If I have an arbitrary list

$$L = [2,3,7]$$

What is the proper notation for the product of all the elements in this list?

My guess is

$$\prod_{x\in L} x = 42$$

or maybe

$$\prod_{i} x_i, x \in [2,3,7] = 42$$

Are either of these correct?

Comment: The first one is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the first one is more standard in mathematics.
$$
\prod_{x\in L} x = 42
$$